# Is there any way for setting the logfile via redis-cli but not editing the redis.config file?

Tags: linux, redis

I am trying to modify the running redis configuration by setting a logfile in it. I cannot edit the **redis.config** file as the redis is running on production. I changed the **dbfilename** parameter using the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the `logfile` using `CONFIG SET`. You can change other config settings, including `loglevel`, but not `logfile` as it is currently unsupported.

You can use `CONFIG GET logfile` to see the current setting value. If empty, it is going to standard output or a TTY.

A little hackish, but you can [redirect the output](https://etbe.coker.com.au/2008/02/27/redirecting-output-from-a-running-process/) using `gdb`.

Comment: Very hackish :)

Comment: guess I will have to edit the **redis.conf** file itself.